# PHP Getting average grade

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I need to get the average number of a grade in a function. Doesn't seem to work completly.. Thanks for your help.
This is what I have so far:

```
<?php
function povprecje($d,$t){
    $v=0;

    foreach($t as $x=>$y){
        foreach($y as $d=>$grade){
            $v = $v+$grade;
            $v = $v/count($grade);

            return $v;
        }
    }
}

$t = array(
    "Student" => array(
        "math"    => 3,
        "algebra" => 4,
        "science" => 4
    )
);

echo povprecje("math",$t);
?>
```

Comment: How is it not working? What is the expected and the actual result?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe You wanted to achieve this?

```
function povprecje($sSubject, $aGrades) {
    $iGradesSum     = 0;
    $iAmount        = 0;    

    foreach($aGrades as $aStudentGrades) {
        if(isset($aStudentGrades[$sSubject])) {
            $iGradesSum+= $aStudentGrades[$sSubject];
            $iAmount++;
        }
    }

    return $iGradesSum / $iAmount;
}
```

Function call:

```
echo povprecje("math", $t);
```

Comment: No, I'm sorry. I was mistaken. I need to call a class, say "math" and get the average number.

Comment: @nejcg Here You go. Updated.